# Create and upload csv file to azure blob storage using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to create csv file using python and than to upload that file to azure blob storage. I am able to create csv file, that part works fine, but when I try to upload the file to blob:

```
blob.upload_blob(data=df.to_csv("capacity.csv",index=False))
```

I get error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\blob.py", line 94, in <module>
    blob.upload_blob(data=df.to_csv("data.csv",index=False))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py", line 83, in wrapper_use_tracer    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_blob_client.py", line 489, in upload_blob   
    options = self._upload_blob_options(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_blob_client.py", line 332, in _upload_blob_options
    raise TypeError("Unsupported data type: {}".format(type(data)))
TypeError: Unsupported data type: <class 'NoneType'>
```

After that I tried to upload some local csv file, just to test if it is working:

```
with open(path_to_file, "rb") as data:
   blob.upload_blob( data=data)
```

And it worked.
I am not sure what is causing this error, I spent some time looking for solution, but nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You are converting a `.csv-File` to csv again:

```
blob.upload_blob(data=df.to_csv("capacity.csv",index=False))
                                 ^
```

But you should convert your DataFrame to csv:

```
blob.upload_blob(data=df.to_csv(index=False))
```

Comment: Thank you bro, you helped me a lot. Your suggestion did not fixed my problem, but you forced me to look again at documentation and than I figured out. Correct approach is: blob.upload_blob(data=df.to_csv(index=False))

Comment: Good to hear! I fixed it in the solution above.